# How should I design my desktop app so I can remotly follow if they are 'alive'

Tags: ping, remote-server

I distribute several computers to my clients where my desktop SW is running. I have a centralized server where users can access some data from those computers via web HTTP. That data is gathered in batch and is not real-time, which is fine. I would like to add a real-time status of the app(s) running on those remote computer. For now I want to display only if app is running and running properly. What would be the best way to do this? Should my app send something to server every few seconds to notify it is still running, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your app sending something to the server every now and then seems like a good idea. Make sure the connection doesn't interfere with the rest of the program though - eg threading it and handling cannot connect situations.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. A heartbeat service would be the answer.

Comment: heartbeat service? any link to example, description of such service!